# The apiv3 does not return joined fields

Tags: api

Not much doc on API and joined table fields... Any special reason I can't get the contact's primary address in a membership query... Basically this

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', array(
  'debug' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("contact_id.display_name", "contact_id.street_address"),
));
```

Only returns contact_id.display_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Membership doesn't have a contact details(apart from `id`) in its API call. To get the address and display name, I think you need to call a chain API -

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'api.Contact.get' => array('return' => "display_name, street_address"),
));
```

More about chaining - https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Chaining

Comment: Ah, I see now... Thanks... That API needs work...